# Не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования

Tags: c++

В чём проблема? И как правильно сделать?

```
    std::string username = RegGetValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, szPath, _T("token"), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, (BYTE*)szBuf, &dwBufLen);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Функция RegGetValue возвращает LSTATUS (число), а не строку.